# Prove that $A \subset \bar{A}$. Where $\bar{A}$ is the set consisting of the points of $A$ and the accumulation points of $A$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ denote the closure of $A$, that is $\bar{A}$, which is the set consisting of the points of $A$ and the accumulation points of $A$.

Prove that 1. $A \subset \bar{A}$. and 2. $\overline{A \cup B} = \bar{A} \cup \bar{B}$.

I don't know where to start, hence why I haven't included an attempt. You don't need to give a direct answer altough it'b appreciated, I would be happy with just some pointing in the right direction...

Comment: Do you mean $\overline{A}$ is the set of all "limit" or "adherent" points of $A$?

Comment: $\bar{A}$ is the set of all points of A, including all 'accumulation/limit' points of A

Comment: Right! I misread the question. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: The first one is then very easy to see. It is in fact the definition of $\bar{A}$. You just mentioned $\bar{A}$ is the set of all points of $A$ **along with** the accumulation points of $A$. So, naturally $A \subseteq \bar{A}$. As for the second, go with proving the two subsethoods. That should not be difficult to see if you merely "attack the definition".

Answer (score 1):

One definition of $\bar{A}$ is that it is the smallest (with respect to inclusion) closed set containing $A$, in which case you have right away that $A\subset\bar{A}$. For the second question, note that
\begin{equation*} A\cup B\subset\bar{A}\cup\bar{B} \end{equation*}
and since the union of two closed sets is closed, it follows from the above definition of closure that $\overline{A\cup B}\subset\bar{A}\cup\bar{B}$. Now, I'll leave it to you to prove the opposite inclusion...in particular, what can you conclude if $x\in\bar{A}\cup\bar{B}$?